# How is plot of p-values distribution related to calculation of the false discovery rate?

Tags: p-value, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

I'm running t-tests for all combinations of pairwise comparisons of average length of stay for patients among 30 hospitals.

My first approach was to use a Bonferroni corrected significance level of .05/(30*29/2) = .05/435 = .00011. However this is setting the bar a bit high for rejection.

Therefore, as suggested in Schweder and Spjotvoll's 1982 article, I first estimated the number of true null hypotheses by plotting the ranked values for (1 - p-value) from all 435 t-tests and then fit a regression line on the linear portion of the plot (the first 100 scores). This required some eyeballing - not terribly rigorous.

The resulting line gives me an estimate of about 140 true hypotheses (where the regression line intercepts the x = 1.00 axis), for a more liberal significance level of .05/140 = .00036.

I know later research by Benjamini & Hochberg have built on Schweder and Spjotvoll's simple approach. How is estimation of the false discovery rate related to the p-value plot technique I've described, or are they equivalent?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use R's ``SimComp`` package with Tukey contrasts? Tukey contrasts mean all pairwise comparisons. ``SimComp`` can deal with heteroskedasticity and provides also simultaneous confidence intervals. Also, it controls FWER which is more appropriate than FDR in your case. Another issue: Durations are often better modelled as exponentially distributed, not normally.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch - Good point. I'm currently using proc glm in SAS to conduct the pairwise comparisons.

Comment: Try pairwise.wilcoxon procedure with adjusted p.values computed for familywise error rate (fwer) control proposed by hochberg or holm. This is a function from R statistical package. Adjusted p.values are transformed p.values so that You can compare each of them separetly with significance level 0.05. I also suggest multcomp package for any p.values corresponding to any test. Also remember that You can construct non-parametric kruskal-Wallis rank test for All 30 groups in one test, before You run 435 post hoc tests.